# C++ Boost - Can't resolve namespace member or container

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/formatters.html) Boost tutorial and cannot figure out why the namespace and containers are not recognized.  I've looked and looked to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

---

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Boost Logger Test
 */

#include <boost/log/core/core.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;

enum severity_level
{
    normal,
    notification,
    warning,
    error,
    critical
};

void init()
{
    boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();

    logging::add_file_log
            (
                    keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
                    keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
                    keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
                    keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"
            );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
            (
                    logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
            );
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    init();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably because you don't compile with the library headers, like `-I/path/to/boost`. Also, post the code as text not images.

Comment: I posted a picture to show the unrecognized elements.  I'll post code now.  I am including the library headers:  INCLUDES = -I/usr/local/arm/include
LIBDIRS  = -L/usr/local/arm/lib

Comment: can you post the error message then?

Comment: Can't resolve namespace member 'add_file_log'

Comment: The others say Can't resolve container 'keywords' etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must

```
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
```

and add

```
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
```

Comment: OK.  Now I just need to find the #includes for the others.  Thank you.  :-)